# Multiple values to subreport

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I a matrix which shows count of Invoices (InvoiceID) with countries on rows and years on headers

```
Country  2001  2002  
US       100   300
UK       200   400
IR       500    90
```

I have requirement of creating a subreport which shows Invoices details. When I click 100(US-2001) on my main report I have to show all the 100 Invoices. I tried this way: since I am doing count of InoviceID in matrix, I tried using `Join(Fields!InvoiceID,", ")` expression on the data text box action (Go to report). on the other side I created a subreport with multivalue parameter. but this approach dint work. Later I discovered that Join will not work rows as it expects only arrays.

later I used `Join(LookupSet(1,1,Fields!InvoiceID.Value, "DatasetName")," / ")` I could join the invoice ids but the problem is, this expression joins all the invoice ID in complete dataset. I just need US-2001 invoices to take to my subreport.

Answer (score 0):

Your subreport should have two parameters:

- `@Year`
- `@Country`

With those two parameters, the subreport can find the clicked invoices. For example, if the following values are passed:

- `@Year` = "2001"
- `@Country` = "UK"

Then it should be able to find those "200" invoices and display their details.

If you base both the main report (that shows `COUNT(InvoiceID)` and the subreport (that shows `Invoice.*` details) on the same view, you're pretty safe in getting consistent results in both reports.

With the "Go to subreport" action you should be able to fill those parameters.